# Opening Child Visualforce page based on parent field value

Tags: visualforce

I have a parent object `Contract__c` and a child record `Risk__c`. 
The parent object has a picklist:
`Classification: high, medium, low`

`Risk__c` has two record types `high` and `low`. The fields for these record types are different, and I have created a visualforce page for each record type, because I need to modify the `save&new` functionality.

When the user enters `high` on `Contract__c`, the user needs to click on the related list button `Create high risk`, which opens the high risk visualforce page. I have another button called `Create medium risk`, which the user should click if `medium` was selected in the `classification` picklist.

The problem is, I want to only display the high button if high was selected in the picklist, and I want to be able to display the medium button, only if medium was selected. Is that possible?

Otherwise I would be happy to just have one button, which has some logic to decide which page to open. But I wouldn't know how to do that.

Tia.

Comment: In case your `Create X risk` button is a custom button why can't you just check the parent's picklist value before redirecting to the creation page? Something like `IF(ISPICKVAL(Classification, "high"), "VisualforcePage1", "VisualforcePage2")`

Comment: But would that be a url, javascript or visualforce page?  When I select visualforce page as my  content source, then I am not able to do that.

Comment: You can redirect to the visualforce page using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create one custom field on your Custom object "**Contract__c**" which holds the name of visualforce page lets call it as "**Page__c**".
- The value of **Page__c** will change according to value of ***Classification: high, medium, low*** 
  e.g.

  ```
  if
      Classification == high
  then 
      page__c = 'HighVFPage';
  ```
- This page__c would be formula field which contains formula like

  ```
  CASE(Classification, "high", "HighVFPage", "medium", "MediumVFPage","LowVFPage")
  ```
- Create List button on child object("**Risk__c**") which contains below code.

  ```
  var pageValue = "{!Contract__c.Page__c}"; 
  var url = "/apex/"+pageValue; 
  parent.window.location = url;
  ```

I hope this will work for you.